# Can't migrate models to MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, django

`Makemigrations` and `migrate` commands work fine and they create files in 'migrations' folder
([migration commands](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RRp1v.png)). But MySQL db does not change([MySQL screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ASWO7.png)). [0001_initial.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pbw1W.png).

Code:

```
from django.db import models

class Student(models.Model):
    student_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    student_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    grade = models.IntegerField()

class Teacher(models.Model):
    teacher_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

settings.py:

```
DATABASES = {
 'default': {  
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',  
    'NAME': 'local_db',  
    'USER': 'user',  
    'PASSWORD': 'password',  
    'HOST': '127.0.0.1',  
    'PORT': '3306',  
    'OPTIONS': {  
        'init_command': "SET sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES'"  
    }  
}
```

}

Comment: do you check the db config in the file ´settings.py´?

Comment: You should share your settings.py file under **Database Configurations**

Comment: Shared settings.py file

Comment: Yesterday, I somehow managed to migrate teacher model, but not student. I deleted mirgations file and table in mysql, so I could try to migrate both. Now, none of them doesn't migrate

Answer (score 0):

1)I dropped every default for django table in db.
2)Cleared migrations folder.
3)Used `python manage.py migrate app1 0001` instead of just `python manage.py migrate` and it worked! Hope it'll help someone